# Fontawesome speed loading problems

Tags: theming

I’m using the Bartik Theme on Drupal 8.5 as a base theme (I have the Fontawesome module: 8.x-2.0 installed and I have the fontawesome being loaded from my local files) and I doing a few changes on my custom theme. In one of  the templates I took over, I used  fontawesome with the tag: `<i class="far fa-comments"></i>`.

Sometimes on loading of the pages, before the icon shows, it appear a small square on his place, and only an instant after the icon loads.
I still have the site on debug mode, but is this behavior normal? How can I make the loading of the icons faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising the contributions of BhargavSushant and Mario Steinitz,   configuring the Fontawesome Module  to load the Font Awesome library from the given source rather than from the local library file is slower option (unless you have a bad server) and also when we are running our site on a “dev” node we should expect delays on loading the icons. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

[Scripts are added to the last in the resulting HTML Page in Drupal 8, and External CSS is added in the head](https://www.drupal.org/node/784626), but external CSS is loaded after internal CSS that is used in modules. This might be creating an unwanted delay in rendering your font awesome styles.

I suggest you minimize the delay of your font awesome script by hosting it on your own server and calling it from there.

Comment: Thanks I just did that and it makes it faster, but still it shows a small square before it loads, any more sugestions please?

Comment: Did you tried put ting both css and font files in the same directory ?

Comment: Can I do that? becouse the fontasome module requires us to place it in a specific path, which is different from the CSS file

Comment: Long story short: The squares are normal behavior as long as the font is still loading from your server. You need to make sure to provide the font (non-blocking) as fast as possible and that your server sends the correct caching tags to your browser, so that the font will be cached for subsequent visits of your site. All that is little related to Drupal, but to an understanding of resource loading (synchronous/asynchronous), pre-loading and caching overall. I suggest, you do some research on these topics first and come back with your specific questions while implementing it in Drupal.

Comment: Mario, great help as you point out probably the issue is because my site is with rebuild_access setting enabled and I also disabled most of the caches to make the development process easier. Thanks